# How Payment Provider Gateway works?

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-gateway

I'm trying to use Magento 2 Documentation to implement my custom credit card module payment, but i'm not able to understand the way Payment Provider Gateway works.

I folowed this doc: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/payments-integrations/bk-payments-integrations.html

What I understand is that it can communicate with the payment gateway I choose, but how to transfer the order info and credit card info to the payment gateway?

So, my custom payment method is showing in the checkout page. I selected it and place order but my gateway provider do not received the informations.

That's my AuthorizationRequest.php file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Ahimsa\PaymentGateway\Gateway\Request;

use Magento\Payment\Gateway\ConfigInterface;
use Magento\Payment\Gateway\Data\PaymentDataObjectInterface;
use Magento\Payment\Gateway\Request\BuilderInterface;

class AuthorizationRequest implements BuilderInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ConfigInterface
     */
    private $config;

    /**
     * @param ConfigInterface $config
     */
    public function __construct(
        ConfigInterface $config
    ) {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    /**
     * Builds ENV request
     *
     * @param array $buildSubject
     * @return array
     */
    public function build(array $buildSubject)
    {
        if (!isset($buildSubject['payment'])
            || !$buildSubject['payment'] instanceof PaymentDataObjectInterface
        ) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Payment data object should be provided');
        }


        /** @var PaymentDataObjectInterface $payment */
        $payment = $buildSubject['payment'];
        $order = $payment->getOrder();
        $billing = $order->getBillingAddress();
        $address = $order->getShippingAddress();

        return [
            'reference' => $order->getOrderIncrementId(),
            'capture' => false,
            'amount' => $order->getGrandTotalAmount(),
            'cardNumber' => '4024007165823435',
            'cardholderName' => 'Bill Gates',
            'expirationMonth' => 02,
            'expirationYear' => 2020,
            'securityCode' => 317,
            'uri' => 'desenvolvedores/v1/transactions'
        ];
    }
}
```

And the TransferFactory.php file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Ahimsa\PaymentGateway\Gateway\Http;

use Magento\Payment\Gateway\Http\TransferBuilder;
use Magento\Payment\Gateway\Http\TransferFactoryInterface;
use Magento\Payment\Gateway\Http\TransferInterface;
use Ahimsa\PaymentGateway\Gateway\Request\MockDataRequest;

class TransferFactory implements TransferFactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @var TransferBuilder
     */
    const URL = 'https://api.userede.com.br/';
    private $transferBuilder;

    /**
     * @param TransferBuilder $transferBuilder
     */
    public function __construct(
        TransferBuilder $transferBuilder
    ) {
        $this->transferBuilder = $transferBuilder;
    }

    /**
     * Builds gateway transfer object
     *
     * @param array $request
     * @return TransferInterface
     */
    public function create(array $request)
    {

        return $this->transferBuilder
            ->setBody(json_encode($request))
            ->setMethod('POST')
            ->setHeaders([
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'Authorization' => 'Basic MTAwMDAyMTA6Y2M3Yzk0MjQ1YjNhNGUxNmJlYmI2ZjE2ZTZiMTFkNjk=',
                'Affiliation' => '10000210'
                ])
            ->setUri('https://api.userede.com.br/desenvolvedores/v1/transactions')
            ->build();
    }
}
```

Is that the right way?

Help please!